# How to add a number and rearrange a date in linux?

Tags: linux

When I do this:

```
 a=cut -c 25-31 <<< 'REFDV.UJH.c01r00.GLOBAL.2000.06.99.9999.MLM.10KM.ZZ00.MM1.00.nc'
```

I got  echo a

```
 2000.06
```

I would like to systematically return a as

```
   01062000
```

always add 01 and arrange it differently

Comment: The answer will depend on your shell. Is it bash? (if so add the `[bash]` tag). Do the same for any other shell. If it is truly just POSIX shell, like dash, etc.,  then your question is fine. But be advised that the answers will be radically different between shells (and in efficiency)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more efficient approach might be to obtain and format the output in one operation using `awk`, i.e.

```
$ awk -F'.' '{ print "01"$6$5 }' <<< 'REFDV.UJH.c01r00.GLOBAL.2000.06.99.9999.MLM.10KM.ZZ00.MM1.00.nc'
01062000
$
```

If you want to save the output to a shell variable named `a`:

```
$ a=$(awk -F'.' '{ print "01"$6$5 }' <<< 'REFDV.UJH.c01r00.GLOBAL.2000.06.99.9999.MLM.10KM.ZZ00.MM1.00.nc')
$ echo "$a"
01062000
$
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ a='REFDV.UJH.c01r00.GLOBAL.2000.06.99.9999.MLM.10KM.ZZ00.MM1.00.nc'

$ d=$(echo $a | cut -d . -f 5-6 --output-delimiter=- | sed 's/\(.*\)/\1-01/')
$ echo $d
2000-06-01

$ date -d "$d" +%d%m%Y
01062000

$ date -d "$d" +%c
Thu 01 Jun 2000 12:00:00 AM CDT
```

Comment: That's a good POSIX approach. If it were tagged bash, you could avoid the subshell with `mydate="01${a:5:2}${a:0:4}"`,. But alas, all we have is [linux] as the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```sh
year=`echo $a | cut -d '.' -f1 `
month=`echo $a | cut -d '.' -f2 `
echo "01$month$year"

nabil@LAPTOP:~$ echo "01$month$year"
01062000
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).